# How to solve an exercise with supply and demand (derivatives)?

Tags: derivatives, economics

Supply and Demand. Supply of a firm is given by S = $e^p$ . Demand is given by $A/P$ .Find the equilibrium condition (supply and demand must be equal). How does the price change when the demand function increases to A'?
Hint: You can use implicit differentiation in the equilibrium condition. Alternatively, you can solve for A and differentiate the inverse function. Once you have an expression, try to guess its sign based on what you know about exponential functions.

In the image, you see my solution (hyperlink). But I do not know what to do next. Please, help me)

Edit: Solution in text:

$Q^S$ = $e^P$
$Q^D = A÷P$

$e^P$ = A÷P
A = P$e^P$

A' = (P$e^P$)' = $e^P$ + P$e^P$

$e^P$ ( 1 + P ) = 0

1 + P = 0

P = -1

P=-1 is a minimum point

$Q^D$ = $A/P$ + $e^P$ (1+P)

[my solution. click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9C1i.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: You use both $P$ and $p$.  They are different, but appear to both be price.  You should define your terms.  Presumably $Q$ is the quantity.  What is $Q^3, Q^P$ in the solution?  They make no sense.  The first line should be two equations, $Q=e^P$b and $Q=\frac AP$ so you can set those equal.  You have multiple equations on a line a number of places.

Comment: @Ross Millikan It was my mistake in MathJax. I fixed it. Please, look at my solution  again

Comment: The book solution is wrong.  You can't have a negative price.  They should be solving $e^P=\frac AP$, which can only be done numerically or using the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The Equilibrium Condition is $Q^S=Q^D$ or $e^P=A/P$ or $$Pe^P=A.$$  We want $\frac{\partial P}{\partial A}.$ Re-write the equilibrium condition as $Pe^P-A=0$ and use implicit differentiation, if $g(x,k)=0$ then $$\frac{dx}{dk}=-\frac{\frac{\partial g}{\partial k}}{\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}}.$$
If we let $g$ be $Pe^P-A$ we find that
$$\frac{dP}{dA}=\frac{1}{e^P(1+P)}$$ and since prices are non-negative, the derivative is positive, so  higher $A$ means a higher price, which makes economic sense: higher demand increases the market price.